# new to laravel. i'm getting an error and i don't know what's wrong

Tags: laravel

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\articles>
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\articles> $php artisan make: migration create_articles_table --create=articles
At line:1 char:6
+ $php artisan make: migration create_articles_table --create=articles
+      ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'artisan' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Think it should be „php artisan make:migration“ instead of „php artisan make: migration“ . There should be no blank space in the command

Comment: yeah. thanks for that one

Answer (score 1):

There should be no space in between `make:` and `migration`. In order to create a table you do not need to write `--create` again.

Try the below command on your command prompt.

```
php artisan make:migration create_articles_table
```